# Create a PDF File based on a range in Google Sheets and send it in Email then delete the file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to button in my sheets where I create a pdf based on a range and send it into email, the recipient of email and subject is also based on a cell range and after the email was sent I want to delete the pdf file on my drive.

I tried this code but it says that the function getAs is not a code, I am self learning coding so in times that I got stucked I ask stackoverflow for help.

```
function sendPdf() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:I35"); // Change this to the range you want to export to PDF
  var pdfName = sheet.getRange("B2:H2").getDisplayValue();
  var blob = range.getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName + '.pdf');

  var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);

  var recipient = sheet.getRange("K2").getValue(); // Cell containing the recipient email address
  var subject = sheet.getRange("B2:H2").getDisplayValue(); // Cell range containing the email subject

  var body = "Good day Sir Mark, I am writing this email to request approval for items rental. Please check the attached email for further details. Thank you :)";

  var options = {
    attachments: [pdfFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
    subject: subject,
    body: body
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, options);
  pdfFile.setTrashed(true); // Delete the PDF file after sending the email

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Email Sent !!')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- At `var blob = range.getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName + '.pdf');`, unfortunately, `getAs` method is not the method of Class Range. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. In this case, I thought that [this information (Author:
  Spencer Easton)](https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70) might be useful.
- As another modification point, I think that `MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, options);` is required to be modified.
- In your script, a PDF file is created with `var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);` and remove with `pdfFile.setTrashed(true);`. In this case, I think that `blob` can be directly used as the attachment file.
- About `sheet.getRange("B2:H2").getDisplayValue()`, in this case, "B2:H2" are merged? And, 2 times of `var pdfName = sheet.getRange("B2:H2").getDisplayValue();` and `var subject = sheet.getRange("B2:H2").getDisplayValue();` are used. I think that this can be used in one time.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function sendPdf() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var pdfName = sheet.getRange("B2:H2").getDisplayValue();
  var recipient = sheet.getRange("K2").getValue();
  var url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=pdf&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}&r1=0&c1=0&r2=35&c2=9`;
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  var body = "Good day Sir Mark, I am writing this email to request approval for items rental. Please check the attached email for further details. Thank you :)";
  var options = {
    to: recipient,
    attachments: [blob],
    subject: pdfName,
    body: body
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(options);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Email Sent !!');

  // DriveApp.getFiles(); // This comment line is used to automatically detect the required scope by the script editor.
}
```

- When this script is run, the range of "A1:I35" of the active sheet is created as PDF data. And, the PDF data is added as an attachment file of the email.

#### Reference:

- [sendEmail(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))